# Using sax.utils how can i add a tag

Tags: python, sax, saxparser

I have the following code that creates an xml doc

```
self.errorlist.append(
            '<testcase classname=%(cls)s name=%(name)s time="%(taken)d">'
            '<%(type)s type=%(errtype)s message=%(message)s><![CDATA[%(tb)s]]>'
            '</%(type)s></testcase>' %
            {'cls': self._quoteattr('.'.join(id.split('.')[:-1])),                         
             'name': self._quoteattr(id.split('.')[-1]),                                   
             'taken': taken,                                                               
             'type': type,                                                                 
             'errtype': self._quoteattr(nice_classname(err[0])),                           
             'message': self._quoteattr(exc_message(err)),                                 
             'tb': escape_cdata(tb),                                                       
             })
```

How can i add a new tag, or new type e.g. "db" 
I tried

```
 self.errorlist.append(
        '<testcase classname=%(cls)s name=%(name)s db=%(db)s time="%(taken)d">'
        '<%(type)s type=%(errtype)s message=%(message)s><![CDATA[%(tb)s]]>'
        '</%(type)s></testcase>' %
        {'cls': self._quoteattr('.'.join(id.split('.')[:-1])),
         'name': self._quoteattr(id.split('.')[-1]),
         'taken': taken,
         'type': type,
         'errtype': self._quoteattr(nice_classname(err[0])),
         'message': self._quoteattr(exc_message(err)),
         'tb': escape_cdata(tb),
         })
```

but got : KeyError: 'db'

i also tried just plain %(db)s but got error:
NameError: global name 'db' is not defined

Following is the import

from xml.sax import saxutils

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved: using the code below, i was abe to get db="mysql" in the XML Doc

```
self.errorlist.append(
            '<testcase classname=%(cls)s name=%(name)s db="%(db)s" time="%(taken)d">'
            '<%(type)s type=%(errtype)s message=%(message)s><![CDATA[%(tb)s]]>'
            '</%(type)s></testcase>' %
            {'cls': self._quoteattr('.'.join(id.split('.')[:-1])),
             'name': self._quoteattr(id.split('.')[-1]),
             'db': self.db,
             'taken': taken,
             'type': type,
             'errtype': self._quoteattr(nice_classname(err[0])),
             'message': self._quoteattr(exc_message(err)),
             'tb': escape_cdata(tb),
             })
```